# How should I treat error.html on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I have a static website at Amazon AWS Cloud S3 bucket. The website is served using CloudFront.

In **Static website hosting** settings under the bucket properties I have specified page `error.html` as **Error document** for the website. Now whenever someone goes to a page that doesn't exist, my custom error document - error.html content is served together with 404 header. That is good.

The problem is when someone navigates directly to the https://www.example.com/error.html the error.html is served with HTTP status code: 200. This means this **page can be crawled by search engine bots and indexed**.

What should I do about this page?

Should I only add **noindex** into error.html `<head>`:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

OR somehow **change the header response** in S3/CloudFront settings? How?

Answer (score 0):

Having 404 response code with the error page response is sufficient for google to ignore the error page from indexing. More info check Google [404 Soft Errors](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181708?hl=en).

However to send 404 response code when directly accessing the url, its not possibly only using S3. For this you need to use CloudFront or a WebProxy infront of S3.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question was not about a not existing page that returns 404 response. It was about accessing the **error.html page-file** that is used as a template for displaying custom error page.

Without any changes it is just a standard page that returns status code 200 which is not good.

Comment: It seems you are right I understood the question wrong, I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks! I also have CloudFront. What should I set there? If error.html returns 404, is it possible to use it as error document?